# Is it possible to capture user and pass by port 18080?

Tags: wireshark

[image]I have an application that authenticates with web server.
I've installed wireshark to sniff traffic and check if is possible to capture user/pass of login user but I can't.

I filter in wireshark by:
tcp.port == 18080
Then I search inside packets by username or password but I can't find anything.
Could you help me please?

Comment: Could you add a screenshot or a sample of your data? Are you using HTTP or HTTPS? If it's encrypted, such as HTTPS, then you can't expect to find any usernames or passwords.

Comment: you might have better luck in [ServerFault](https://serverfault.com/) for capturing packets.

Comment: I attach you a screenshoot